# Updating the stack on Heroku

Tags: perl, heroku

I have a small application running there using the [heroku-buildpack-perl](https://github.com/miyagawa/heroku-buildpack-perl) buildpack. It's just a small [Plack](http://p3rl.org/Plack) application and it had been running fine for about two years.

But then, Heroku informed me that the stack it was running on was getting too old and I needed to upgrade it. "Just run a new deploy and the application will be installed to a new stack!" said they or something like that.

I inniciated a new deploy by creating an empty commit in the git repository, the deployment ran... but the application was crashing. From the logs I realised they updated the Perl version, but the deployment didn't update my XS libraries (I use [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib), not sure if that's part of the buildpack or I set it up manually when creating the application back then).

In the end, I deleted the application and recreated it on the new stack, which worked OK. I don't keep any data anywhere so it was not a problem. What's the correct way to update the stack, though? There should be an option somewhere that tells Heroku to rebuild the dependencies, right?

Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11133022).

Comment: I ran into the same issue on github actions with a cached local::lib when they updated their Ubuntu images and the Perl version changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting Heroku stack. In this case to `heroku-20` equivalent with Ubuntu 20.04

```
$ heroku stack:set heroku-20
```

Since you are using a different stack, the old cache may not be compatible. Clearing cache:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
$ heroku builds:cache:purge -a appname
```

Triggering a rebuild:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
$ git push heroku master
```

Note:

You have to make sure that the buildpack you are using is compatible with `heroku-20`. If it is not it will not work. You will have to wait for the maintainer to update, use a different buildpack or fix the buildpack yourself and use that.
If you follow this step by step it is similar to deploying an entirely fresh app.

Comment: Yes, purging the cache helped!